# 404 error installing Java JDK with ansible

Tags: java, java-8, ansible, installation, yaml

I'm trying to install Java using ansible and I've seen someone have the same problem on Reddit before [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/91twfn/installing_oracle_java_with_get_url/). This is the `yaml` file for ansible

```
    - name: download java
      get_url:
        url: "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/10.0.2+13/19aef61b38124481863b1413dce1855f/jre-10.0.2_linux-x64_bin.rpm"
        dest: ~/
        headers: 
          Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie
```

I'm trying to run this (with a different link) and I keep getting a `HTTP Error 404: Not Found`
. It's the same result even if I use the same link too.

Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks

Edit, I'm trying it directly in the terminal with `wget`. I ran
`wget --no-check-certificate -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/11+28/55eed80b163941c8885ad9298e6d786a/jdk-11_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`
and the output is

```
$ wget --no-check-certificate -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/11+28/55eed80b163941c8885ad9298e6d786a/jdk-11_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
--2019-01-23 18:38:29--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/11+28/55eed80b163941c8885ad9298e6d786a/jdk-11_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 184.29.106.250
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|184.29.106.250|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/11+28/55eed80b163941c8885ad9298e6d786a/jdk-11_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz [following]
--2019-01-23 18:38:29--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/11+28/55eed80b163941c8885ad9298e6d786a/jdk-11_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.56.112.136
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.56.112.136|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/11+28/55eed80b163941c8885ad9298e6d786a/jdk-11_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz?AuthParam=1548297629_d1111e625149847f66878eb0ddd67c86 [following]
--2019-01-23 18:38:29--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/11+28/55eed80b163941c8885ad9298e6d786a/jdk-11_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz?AuthParam=1548297629_d1111e625149847f66878eb0ddd67c86
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|184.29.106.250|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/11+28/55eed80b163941c8885ad9298e6d786a/jdk-11_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz?AuthParam=1548297629_d1111e625149847f66878eb0ddd67c86 [following]
--2019-01-23 18:38:29--  https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/11+28/55eed80b163941c8885ad9298e6d786a/jdk-11_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz?AuthParam=1548297629_d1111e625149847f66878eb0ddd67c86
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|184.29.106.250|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-01-23 18:38:30 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: `I'm trying to run this (with a different link)` - we'll probably need to see the actual link. If you're getting a 404, that probably means the link is incorrect, because 404 means `not found`.

Comment: I'm also trying it with the same link assuming that would work. It also doesn't work

Comment: I've edited the question since using `wget` directly doesn't seem to be working either. I'm not sure what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripted download of Java JDKs and JREs from Oracle's main download sites has always been somewhat problematic.  The problem is twofold:

1. Versions disappear from the main download site once they go EOL.  (And with Oracle's new release cadence, this happens pretty quickly for non-LTS versions ... like Java 10.)
2. Oracle want you to do the "click through agreement" thing, and they occasionally change the way it is implemented.  This tends to break scripts (Ansible, etc) that people use to automate deployment.

Possible solutions:

1. Manually download a copy of the Oracle Java release to your own infrastructure, and change your deployment scripts to deploy from there rather than the Oracle site.
2. Use OpenJDK ... which gives you more options for obtaining the deployables.
3. Switch to Java 11.  Java 10 is (already) EOL.
4. If the new release cadence is troublesome, restrict yourself to LTS versions; i.e. Java 8, Java 11, Java 14, ...

Answer (score 0):

It's been my experience that unless I own the server and am doing something funky with it, 404 codes usually really are because that url doesn't exist. Usually, in the case of wget, I've mistyped something.

As far as I can tell, this case is no different. Copying your link into my browser directly yields this page:
[404 error from oracle.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b4PQ.png)

What is the correct link? I unfortunately couldn't tell you.

The way I see it you have 2 options:

1) Verify the link is correct and that you've typed it correctly, or
2) Go to Oracle's site in a browser and try to download the version of Java you want/need.

Hope this helps!